# I keep getting "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.net.URL.toExternalForm()" because "location" is null."

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception

```
package HotelManagement;

import javax.swing.*; 

public class HotelManagementSystem extends JFrame{
    HotelManagementSystem(){
        setSize(1366,768);
        setLocation(100,100);
        ImageIcon i1 = new ImageIcon(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("icons/hotel.jpg"));
        JLabel image = new JLabel(i1);
        add(image);

        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new HotelManagementSystem();        
    }

}
```

error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot
> invoke "java.net.URL.toExternalForm()" because "location" is null.

This is my code and I have icons folder which contains hotel.jpg in src folder of the project in eclipse. I tried using "System.getProperty("user.dir")" and also tried using "./icons/hotel" and
"(System.getProperty("user.dir")+ ".\icons\hotel.jpg")" and everything I found on internet.

Comment: does the file exist? does it exist where you think it exists? Where do you think that path will look for a file?

Comment: couldn't understand you

Comment: most likely it's not looking in the directory you think it's looking

Comment: Please tell me a way to fix it

Comment: put the file in the right directory

Comment: The error says `location` is `null`, but your code does not contain a variable or field named `location`. Please show the full error including the stack trace.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.net.URL.toExternalForm()" because "location" is null
 at java.desktop/javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(ImageIcon.java:234)
 at HotelManagementSystem/HotelManagement.HotelManagementSystem.<init>(HotelManagementSystem.java:10)
 at HotelManagementSystem/HotelManagement.HotelManagementSystem.main(HotelManagementSystem.java:20)

Comment: This `new ImageIcon(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("icons/hotel.jpg"))` will be looking for the `hotel.jpg` in the `HotelManagement` package.  Depending on your IDE and build system will, however, change where you need to store it in order for it to be picked up

Comment: Your file is not a "system resource".

Answer (score -3):

I guess that the problem exists in setLocation(100,100), which isn't
displayed. If you show the code for that method, maybe we can help.

As Stultuske wrote, you can often suspect that a file is missing or
is in the wrong place...

Comment: But I can access my file in that folder manually even when I am copying the path for the file, it's the same path